# catch menu positon, and edit menu after creation

Tags: javascript, dojo, contextmenu

I'm working with the `dijit.Menu` widget, but I don't know how to do some things:

- How can I catch te position of the top left corner of a dijit context menu?
- How can I know witch dome node belongs to the dijit menu, (to do that I write into the menu the DOM node id and I find it with `dojo.byId`, but I don't think its the best way)
- How can I dinamycally change a menu, in other words I need to create a menu and some time after I need to add some submenus.

Comment: At least provide a link to dijit

Answer (score 0):

Each menu has a property domNode that is linked to the top-level DOM node used to display the menu.  Check out the [api](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dijit.Menu).